# Removal of Next Lines from Notepad huge data

Tags: alignment, notepad++, line, cpu-word, notepad

[Hi, I have this data of Bricks which are separated by Next line, I want all to be in the from of Last Line. I can't do it manually one by one because it's very huge data. Can anyone please guide me the easiest way or built in functionality of notepad or notepad++. Thank you 
Click the link to see my file and data.
Regards,
Mubasher Aqeel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaKGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Use "Line Operations" to remove line breaks**

You just need to remove the new lines. Using Notepad++ that is as simple as:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (to select everything)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (which is the shortcut for "Edit → Line Operations → Join Lines")

---

**Use search/replace**

Alternatively you can do it more manually using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Replace)
Choose "extended" under "Search Mode" and replace occurrences of "\r\n" (line breaks) with a blank.